# Synchronizing JavaScript and Java object lifecycles on Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-webview

I'm using addJavascriptInterface() to pass commands between Java and JavaScript in Android.  Each time a new JavaScript object is created I make a call to a Java function to create a new corresponding Java object.

Is there any way to find out when the JavaScript object is being freed and marked for garbage collection so I can make a call to the corresponding Java object?  Does JavaScript provide something like "finalize" in Java?

Comment: Why...? Also even assuming you had something like that in JavaScript (which I don't believe there is) what would you call on the Java object to force the GC to to collect it or what would you do to even mark it for collection? It sounds like you're over-engineering something here.

Comment: I'm making a JS interface for a Java library.  For each JS object created I created a new Java object and keep it along with an index in a collection.  If I know the JS object is removed I can remove the Java object from the collection and it'll be GC'ed.